# Close properly splash-screen

Tags: python, wxpython, splash-screen

I did a code to display a splash-screen when my programm is opening.

```
def main():
    application = wx.App(False)
    splash = show_splash()
    frame = MainWindow()
    frame.Show(True)
    splash.Destroy()
    application.MainLoop()
```

But the splash-screen appears and disappears juste before the program close.
I fixed it with two lines of code but it's ugly:

```
def main():
    application = wx.App(False)
    splash = show_splash()
    frame = MainWindow()
    frame.Show(True)
    splash.Destroy()
    splash.Hide()
    application.MainLoop()
    plash.Destroy()
```

My question is: Why the splashscreen appears when I close the programm with the first code and have you a best solution instead of the second code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the wxPython demo.  The actual demo code has a splash screen.  It implements a 'MyApp' and the splash is created shown within the OnInit method.

Here a working sample based on some stuff I did some time ago and what is done in the demo.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#!/usr/bin/env python

import wxversion
wxversion.select('3.0-classic', True)

import wx
from wx.lib.mixins.inspection import InspectionMixin

import wx.lib.sized_controls as sc

print(wx.VERSION_STRING)

class MySplashScreen(wx.SplashScreen):
    def __init__(self):
        #bmp =  wx.Image(opj(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.split(__file__)[0],"bitmaps","splash.png")))).ConvertToBitmap()
        bmp = wx.ArtProvider.GetBitmap(wx.ART_QUESTION, wx.ART_OTHER, wx.Size(64, 64))
        wx.SplashScreen.__init__(self, bmp,
                                 wx.SPLASH_CENTER_ON_SCREEN | wx.SPLASH_TIMEOUT, #  | wx.STAY_ON_TOP,
                                 3000, None, -1)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnClose)
        self.fc = wx.FutureCall(2000, self.ShowMain)


    def OnClose(self, evt):
        # Make sure the default handler runs too so this window gets
        # destroyed
        evt.Skip()
        self.Hide()

        # if the timer is still running then go ahead and show the
        # main frame now
        if self.fc.IsRunning():
            self.fc.Stop()
            self.ShowMain()

    def ShowMain(self):
        frame = MainFrame(None, title="A sample frame")
        frame.Show()
        if self.fc.IsRunning():
            self.Raise()



class MainFrame(sc.SizedFrame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        kwds["style"] = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.FULL_REPAINT_ON_RESIZE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL

        super(MainFrame, self).__init__(*args, **kwds)

        self.SetTitle("A sample")
        self.Centre(wx.BOTH)

        paneContent = self.GetContentsPane()

        # lets add a few controls
        for x in range(5):
            wx.StaticText(paneContent, -1, 'some string %s' % x)

        paneBtn = sc.SizedPanel(paneContent)
        paneBtn.SetSizerType('horizontal')
        # and a few buttons
        for x in range(3):
            wx.Button(paneBtn, -1, 'a button %s' % x)


        self.Fit()


class BaseApp(wx.App, InspectionMixin):

    """The Application, using WIT to help debugging."""

    def OnInit(self):
        """
        Do application initialization work, e.g. define application globals.
        """
        self.Init()
        self._loginShown = False
        splash = MySplashScreen()

        return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = BaseApp()
    app.MainLoop()
```